Mysterious AWS SES 421 error on max message count per session
tl;dr We have used AWS SES for several years from a few dozen servers, and recently have been getting an error regularly for just one. "Code: 421, response: Connection closed by server. Maximum message count per session reached." We are not able to understand or resolve it.
Details
We have SES sending limits of 100 emails per second and 500k emails per day. Our servers send either to US East or Canada Central. We use the Pear Net_SMTP and Pear Mail packages to send emails over port 465 via AWS SES. Each server sends bulk email messages in batches of 1000 using two processes. Only a few are sending to the Canada Central endpoint, and only one of them is running into this problem. Its load is not significantly different than other VPSes that have never had this problem.
The problematic VPS has been getting an error on a fairly regular basis but it is not all the time. The jobs get through part of a batch before failing. The response is "code: 421, response: Connection closed by server. Maximum message count per session reached."
We understand that 4xx codes indicate it is a temporary failure but we are interested in understanding if there is anything we can do to prevent this response.
With our premium support from AWS we managed to get a not very helpful explanation:

There can be a number of causes for a “421 connection closed by server
error”. The error message that you have shared suggests that the error
is caused by either to many connections from the email sending
application, or congestion on the SMTP endpoint.
These errors are transient, or temporary errors that occur when there
is a spike in concurrent connections to an SMTP endpoint that exceeds
the limit of connections available to the SMTP endpoint server.
Once the congestion has decreased, connections to the SMTP endpoint
server are no longer rejected with a 421 error.
To mitigate the chance of a 421 error occurring you can:

Reduce the number of concurrent emails sent to an SMTP endpoint during a single session.

Implement backoff and retry logic [1] in your sending application to slow down the number of connection requests and retry the
connections once the SMTP endpoint congestion has cleared. I have
included another document that has sample code on implementing retry
logic [2] and retry logic with a backoff pattern [3].


Please refer to our SES user guide for a detailed list of error codes
returned by SMTP endpoints which may assist you to investigate any
other errors that you observe with connections to an SES SMTP endpoint
[4].

We have checked and do not believe that we are getting close to either our daily limit or the number of emails per second limits on our account. We are probably sending a maximum of less than 10 per second to Canada Central aggregating across the VPSes. The more specific error message we actually get is about the number of emails per session, not the number of messages per second. Because we are using standard PEAR libraries we don't see how it could be something odd in our SMTP implementation.
We have reduced the number of processes sending to 1 on this server with no change in SES errors.
This is impacting throughput for this client as instead of sending 1000 emails every 5 minutes it is getting perhaps 350 before this error causes the job to fail.

"suggests that the error is caused by either to many connections from the email sending application, or congestion on the SMTP endpoint" - maybe that congestion is due to the outgoing connections from SES? Some email recipient domains might be especially slow handling mail from your Canada Central endpoint? It does seem like more of a systemic problem than a transient one ...
